# Help need to develop CUBE and DOOR transition using Shader Effect in WPF

Tags: wpf, shader, pixel-shader

I need to develop CUBE and DOOR transition in my WPF application using Shader effect. I have looked [CodePlex Shader library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/) but it doesn't give CUBE and DOOR transition. I am new to pixel shader have limited knowledge to write my own shader file.Any pointer or help ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Those types of transitions are easier to do using the 3D features of WPF rather than a shader.

- [Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) has Cube, 2-Door and Flip transitions which sound like what your after.
- [FluidKit](http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) has a Cube transition too.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Kris, But i need to implement some more transitions which i getting trough Shader Effect, i want to same logic for all the transition.